# Android - change background resource twice with pause between

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am trying to set a button to green for 1 second, then back to red. But It won't change to green anymore, if I comment out the "change to red" part, it will turn green fine. I have used `Log.d` and it shows that there is a second difference between changing from "change to green" to "change to red" so you should see the green before the red, but for some reason this is not working.

Any Ideas?

```
public void level1() throws InterruptedException {
    int Low = 1000;
    int High = 3000;
    int t = r.nextInt(High-Low) + Low;
    Thread.sleep(t);
    handleTime.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i = r.nextInt(5);
            switch(i) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    setGreen(tLeft);
                    tLActive = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    tLActive = false;
                    setRed(tLeft);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                try {
                    setGreen(tRight);
                    tRActive = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    tRActive = false;
                    setRed(tRight);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    setGreen(center);
                    cActive = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    cActive = false;
                    setRed(center);
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                try {
                    setGreen(bLeft);
                    bLActive = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    bLActive = false;
                    setRed(bLeft);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                try {
                    setGreen(bRight);
                    bRActive = true;
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    bRActive = false;
                    setRed(bRight);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setGreen(ImageButton b) {
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green);
    Log.d("green", "green");
}

private void setRed(ImageButton b) {
    b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red);
    Log.d("red", "red");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You able to use `Handler.class`

As simple example:

```
setGreenColor();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
   setRedColor();
  }
}, 1000);
```

where postDelayed will be called in UI thread.

Comment: Yeah, you can reuse the `handleTime` `Handler` though.

Answer (score 0):

The `Runnable` in this case runs on the UI thread. The same thread responsible for drawing. But drawing is not immediate instead the UI element gets invalidated because it wants to be redraw and when the UI thread has time it will preform the redraw.

```
{ //the essence of the runnable code
  setGreen(bRight); //UI element is invalidated, it wants to be redrawn green
  Thread.sleep(1000); //UI thread is tied up here (blocked) so nothing can happen on UI
  setRed(bRight); //UI element is invalidated again, it wants to be redrawn red now
                  // replacing the green before it's even been seen
} //end of runnable code
//now the redrawing occurs, and it will only be red.
```

As Eldar Mensutov points out one solution is to post another runnable with a delay. That way the UI thread will not be blocked by the `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: but surely putting the `setRed` in the finally bracket will let it be redrawn to green first?

Comment: No, `finally` just means "if there was an exception or not make sure you do this after".